Interface between threaded and asynchronous parts of an application in Python
I'm helping develop a Python application which collects data from several sensors and manages a server to send those data to a web application (React) to display. The application is supposed to work on a Variscite board with Yocto.
My initial approach was based on multithreading, which worked fine on Windows and WSL, but on Yocto it went into the weirdest issues. Some methods executed up until the last line, but refused to return, literally just hanging at the return line. In other places, data were put into queues, but an associated threading.Condition failed to perform the notification.
We decided to try an asynchronous approach instead of multithreading, which seems to solve our issues so far. Unfortunately, the interface of one of our sensors, provided externally, inherently relies on threading.
My question is, how bad (unsafe) would it be to have a threading-asyncio interface in the app? The idea would be to use threading to collect data from the sensor and put them into a queue, which would then be periodically checked and consumed in an async way. Are there any precautions I can take to make it safer or ways to make it more elegant? I'm rather new to asyncio, so even basic advice on that would be appreciated.

Could you show some code examples? I had a really bad time mixing asyncio and multithreading in python but as far I know it is not impossible.

@Maciek I can to to some extent, I guess (it's work I'm doing for my company and it's not going to be open source). What would you like to see - the hanging methods, the sensor interface, the new asyncio+multithreading data communication?

it is not hard to mix threading and async in Python - and a few popular "async" libraries do that under the hood. The asyncio contains a few methods that allow for this.
The hardest part would be this misbhabior of threads on the yocto environment you are mentioning. Apart from that, just await for an loop.run_in_executor call for your sync code.
